# How can I add a mp3 track to a simple OpenGL game?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a simple shooter, using basic opengl functionality (glut and glui). I'd like to add a couple of mp3 tracks to the game to play conditionally (level start, death, etc.)

Comment: Which platform(s) are you targeting? What programming language are you using?

Comment: I'm using C++. It's a Windows game, also it's a school project so I'm not allowed to use game engines.

Comment: What I could find was simply this: http://www.devmaster.net/articles/openal-tutorials/lesson1.php and an explanation as to how openGL don't include sound and that you should use openAL for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If don't need any special features such as directional sound, the [MCIWnd functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd798215%28VS.85%29.aspx) are a simple way to play audio files.